# Transforming List<string> into a tokenised string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings in a List container class that look like the following:

```
MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItemX
..
..
..
..
MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItem99
```

What I am trying to do is transform the string, using LINQ, so that the first item for each of the tokenised string is removed.

This is the code I already have:

```
protected static List<string> _menuItems = GetMenuItemsFromXMLFile();
_menuItems.Where(x => x.Contains(menuItemToSearch)).ToList();
```

First line of code is returning an entire XML file with all the menu items that exist within an application in a tokenised form;

The second line is saying 'get me all menu items that belong to menuItemToSearch'. 
menuItemToSearch is contained in the delimited string that is returned.  How do I remove it using linq?

**EXAMPLE**

**Before transform: MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItem99**

**After transform : MenuItem|subItem99**

Hope the example illustrates my intentions
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can take a substring from the first position of the pipe symbol `'|'` to remove the first item from a string, like this:

```
var str = "MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItemX";
var dropFirst = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('|')+1);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Er1T9V)

Apply this to all strings from the list in a LINQ `Select` to produce the desired result:

```
var res = _menuItems
    .Where(x => x.Contains(menuItemToSearch))
    .Select(str => str.Substring(str.IndexOf('|')+1))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri  Your solution does not help me at all - This is what I am doing already. Thankyou das that was exactly what I needed.  Looks so simple now!! :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sth like this can help you.

```
var regex = new Regex("[^\\|]+\\|(.+)");
var list = new List<string>(new string[] { "MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItem99", "MainMenuItem|MenuItem|subItem99" });
var result = list.Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p)).Select(p => regex.Match(p).Groups[1]).ToList();
```

This should work correctly.